# Directed graph: Faster algorithm finding areas with only one "entrance"

Tags: c#

I have a directed graph consiting of objects each knowing the objects pointing at it and the objects it points to (m:n).
I have one object beeing the start node.
I am searching areas with only one entrance. These areas may contain loops and branches and such. The only condition is that you can not enter these areas from outside without passing one specific node.

I developed a simple algorithm solving this problem:

foreach node beeing a branch
{
    Mark all nodes which can be reached from the current one
    Unmark all marked nodes, at which a node not beeing marked points, until there are no more such nodes
}

The problem is:
it gets really, really slow is there are more than 1000 nodes with lots of branches, so the program freezes for some seconds or so and if i stop it using a debugger it is always executing this particular algorithm. This is a problem in special cases but i am going to automate it, so i want it to be fast.

The bad performance is not really surprising, because if there is a branch at start which re-unites after 5 nodes the first 995 nodes are marked and 990 unmarked again one by one.
:( But i have no better idea.

Is there any way of solving this problem faster?

Info about the graphs: Most nodes (about 80%) are just links having exactly one predecessor and one following node, but throwing these away is a really bad idea, because i need them later. Also i am working with the objects in memory, so there are some slight modifications (replacements, removing and adding link nodes)

Comment: I'd be curious to know what your application is for this algorithm. Is this an academic problem, or is there some real-world problem that you're solving here? I am always interested to learn about real-world applications of algorithms.

Comment: I am using it to find ifs and loops and stuff in a very flexible way in a decompiler. It works very well, also for obfuscated code except for the speed in really big methods. Such regions are characterized best by that they have no incoming gotos and follow a branch or a recursion

Comment: FYI such a region of code is called a "basic block". If you are doing literature searches for techniques for code flow analysis, try looking for that term.

Comment: I mean no incoming gotos from outside. not no incoming gotos from inside....

Comment: Ah, I see, so you are looking for units that are *larger* than basic blocks that have only one entrypoint into them.  An interesting problem!

Comment: Ultimate someone actually understood the question right. :)
Btw i just looked at your profile and it's funny that you work on the c# compiler while i am trying to build a c# decompiler

Comment: That is amusing! I don't know the solution to your problem but I would be interested in learning if you find out anything. Also, I'll ask around the team; I am not very well versed in graph theory. Perhaps someone else here has already seen this problem.

Comment: I asked around and no one knew offhand of a fast solution. Something that is not quite clear: do you have a *specific* "gateway" node in mind and you want to identify all the code that can only be accessed through this node, or are you trying to identify the set of *all possible* "gateway" nodes, that is, all the nodes in the program whose removal would render some fragment of code unreachable? The former seems easy compared to the latter.

Comment: I am searching all gateway nodes, but finding potential ones for loops and ifs is no problem at all and fast enough.
The rersults generated by the simple algorithm above are absolutely satisfying! But it just could be a bit faster

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your situation correctly, you are looking for what is, in graph theory, called an [*articulation point*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articulation_point) or *cut vertex*. The Wikipedia page that is linked to describes a very efficient algorithm for detecting such points. Note that the algorithm is based on [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), of which you should have a good understanding if you want to implement the algorithm. Also, if your graph contains many thousand nodes, you need to implement the depth-first search iteratively by using a stack, rather than recursively (which is the standard way of implementing it) - otherwise, your program will probably cause a stack overflow when given a large graph.

Comment: This does not seem very helpful to me:  I have a directed graph, no undirected. And Connected does mean that there is a path FROM THE START NODE to the particular node. I am searching all nodes where all paths from startnode to this node go through one particular 3rd node. Paths may not go backwards, onbly in direction of the arrows.